# Isn't there something wrong with the emphasized time constraints?

Tags: meaning

"The ambitious long-term plan was for twenty English ships to sail ***annually*** through the Mediterranean ***during the winter*** months, with sufficient commodities to turn a profit in Turkey." (Jerry Brotton, *This Orient Isle- Elizabethan England and the Islamic World*)

Comment: What do you think is wrong? What do you think is meant by *annually*? Please [expand your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/546490/edit) to add that: don't answer in comments.

Comment: Annually - once a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the time structure. "*Annually*" means "*every year*", "*regularly at a frequency of a year*", "*repeated every year*" or similar adverbial concepts. To sail during the months of winter every year is to sail annually at that time of the year, as opposed to sailing at some other time such as summer. Other examples: *We sailed annually to Greece in May*; *we sailed annually to Antarctica during the southern summer*; *we worked weekly on Monday*.